# How to find the number of files changed from one commit to another in git

Tags: git

I am working on a git repository which contains huge number of files changed b/w one commit to another, how to extract the number of files changes b/w commits.

Comment: Maybe `git whatchanged`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB It looks like a good answer. Why do you put that in comment and not as an answer? I'm sorry, sometimes I just don't get it.

Comment: @Oltarus: OK, done :-) Didn't seem big enough to warrant an answer, and I'm not sure if it really meets the needs. After checking some docs, though, it seems that it does!

Comment: For more recent visitors, with newer git versions, the following will more or less give you the information that OP was looking for:
`git show --oneline --name-only commit_hash_a..commit_hash_b`
This of course will also print the commit message along with the file list. But good enough for simple use-cases.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

EDIT: "this will always count the files plus one, cause the `--format=oneline` includes the commit-hash/header" as mentioned by c00kiemon5ter

---

The `git whatchanged` tool shows you a summary of files that were modified. By itself it lists all commits, but you can also limit it to just the recent *n* commits:

```
git whatchanged -1
```

To count files:

```
git whatchanged -1 --format=oneline | wc -l
```

See `git help whatchanged` for [details](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged).

Comment: note that this will always count the files plus one, cause the `--format=oneline` includes the commit-hash/header.

Comment: `git whatchanged -1 --format=oneline | tail -n +2 | wc -l`

Comment: From `man git-whatchanged`; "The command is kept primarily for historical reasons." "New users are encouraged to use git-log(1) instead."

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: This answer is kept primarily for historical reasons. New users are encouraged to find a different answer instead :-)

Comment: Since OP seems to have asked about getting number of changed files for all commits and not just one, the following answer seems to be fitting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40777727/2184166

Answer (score 32):

Apart from the above listed methods you can do this too:

`git diff HEAD^..HEAD --name-only` - will give the list of files changed between `HEAD` and one revision before HEAD (`HEAD^`). You can replace `HEAD^` with a SHA1 of the "from" commit and `HEAD` with the SHA1 of the "to" commit:

`git diff <SHA1-of-from-commit>..<SHA1-of-to-commit> --name-only`

So if you pipe the output to `wc -l` it should give you the number of files changed between commits.

Comment: Much more useful to be able to count files between arbitrary commits - not just the files changed in a single commit. Note that it also works with branch names and tags (and of course other commit shorthands in addition to HEAD and HEAD^)

Comment: This definitely helped when I was looking for the total files changed between my branch and master.  `git diff master..HEAD`

Comment: I was looking to count the files changed between two branches.  This was the most helpful answer.  The command I ended up with was `git diff master..HEAD --name-only --oneline --stat | wc -l`.

Answer (score 26):

```
git show --stat
```

This gives the list of files changed like this:

1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

Optionally you can add the commit code if you don't want to get the information from the latest.

```
git show --stat {commit code without brackets}
```

Comment: Use `--shortstat` to get straight to the point: `git show --shortstat <hash>`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show for more options.

Answer (score 14):

use this:

```
git log --oneline --name-status <HASH> -1
```

eg:

```
$ git log --oneline --name-status bb3ae49 -1
M       .vim/spell/en.utf-8.add
M       .vim/spell/en.utf-8.add.spl
```

---

this works just like

```
git whatchanged --oneline --name-status <HASH> -1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since using `git whatchanged` is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

In windows:

```
git whatchanged -1 --format=oneline | find /v /c ""
```

The important windows-specific piece is that you must replace the wc command used in other solutions with this:

```
  | find /v /c ""
```