# How can I get git log to print the full hash and short stats of each commit on one line?

Tags: git, format

I would like to get this kind of output with git command line:

```
bcfd649de8850e3bfc9584eb12be8fe136ca6985 3 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

I'm currently using `git log --shortstat --reverse --pretty=oneline`, but it's actually not a single line and the comment is useless to me:

```
bcfd649de8850e3bfc9584eb12be8fe136ca6985 Added ActionController#cookies[] as a reader for @cookies that'll return the value of the cookie instead of 
3 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137477/how-to-get-git-log-with-short-stat-in-one-line

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For anyone landing here for an answer to "how to get git log one line full commit hash", as I did, there is a flag for the `git log` which prints the non-abbreviated commit hash.

It's called [--no-abbrev-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---no-abbrev-commit). Documentation reads as:

> Show the full 40-byte hexadecimal commit object name. This negates --abbrev-commit, either explicit or implied by other options such as "--oneline". It also overrides the log.abbrevCommit variable.

**TL;DR:** Here is the command for the one-line output with the full commit hash:

`git log --oneline --no-abbrev-commit`

**Note:** It has been brought up by an anonymous user that the order of the flags as mentioned above matters since the `--oneline` makes the `--no-abbrev-commit` flag meaningful to the `git` command.

Comment: The same can be achieved with `git log --pretty=oneline`.

Answer (score 21):

You can define your own format consisting only of the full hash, and pipe the output of `git log` to `awk` (**edit**: or `sed`, [as proposed by jthill in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050251/how-can-i-get-git-log-to-print-the-full-hash-and-short-stats-of-each-commit-on-o/29050898?noredirect=1#comment46341838_29050898)) in order to replace newlines by spaces where needed (see [this](https://serverfault.com/a/375098)):

```sh
git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" --shortstat | awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"'
```

or

```
git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" --shortstat | sed 'N;N;y/\n/ /'
```

#### Test

```sh
$ git log --pretty=tformat:"%H" --shortstat | awk 'ORS=NR%3?" ":"\n"'
4da27ca5dc8469f19b1524a5dd381aad76f96c69   4 files changed, 26 insertions(+)
60c1e011aadc1bdbf38dde989d0f0497925678d9   4 files changed, 34 insertions(+)
f0e6da70616337f135190dc7f68e22678a7af2ff   4 files changed, 34 insertions(+)
95ea8a002f66a249946a78deb362a2e697dfb80a   4 files changed, 44 insertions(+)
9854efba2301d520bc4fe1a102e102f299ae127d   1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
c8ee6b36a545c67b2443eea499bf046dd1e2233d   4 files changed, 29 insertions(+)
2d4374edd2d2820f05853b4add9fc5ddba1506ac   4 files changed, 42 insertions(+)
$
```

Comment: Or `| sed 'N;N;y/\n/ /'`

Comment: This will fail in some cases because some commits don't have stats. When the script hits a "stats-less" commit, the output will break. I found a solution for that on a personal project https://github.com/dreamyguy/gitlogg, and I posted my approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137477/how-to-get-git-log-with-short-stat-in-one-line/37497880#37497880