# show commit size for each commit based on lines of code while finding coding days

Tags: python, python-3.x, git

I am trying to find the coding days(active days) along with number of commits and each commit's size per coding days. This is what I meant to say

```
{
   "2014-05-2": {
      "commit_count": "1",
      "commit": [{ 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 10, 'lines_removed': 4 }}]
    },
    "2014-05-3": {
      "commit_count": "2",
      "commit": [
          { 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 10, 'lines_removed': 4 }},
          { 'commit_hash': {'lines_added': 14, 'lines_removed': 0 }},
        ]
    }
}
```

For now, I could only find coding days and number of commits this way

```
async def get_coding_days(self, author, before, after):
    cmd = (
        f'git log {self.conf.get("branch", "master")} --author="{author}" --date=short'
    )
    cmd += ' --pretty=format:"%ad %an"'
    if before:
        cmd += f' --before="{before}"'
    if after:
        cmd += f' --after="{after}"'
    results = get_proc_out([cmd, "sort", "uniq -c"]).splitlines()
    np_results = np.array(results)
    stripped_array = np.char.strip(np_results)
    for result in stripped_array:
        second_space_pos = result.find(" ", 2)
        if second_space_pos > 2:
            count_with_time = result[0 : second_space_pos - 1]
            [commit_count, coding_day] = count_with_time.split(" ")
            author = result[second_space_pos + 1 :]
            # default_dict[author].append(
            #     {"commit_count": commit_count, "coding_day": coding_day}
            # )
            if author not in self.coding_days:
                self.coding_days[author] = []
            self.coding_days[author].append(
                {coding_day: {"commit_count": commit_count}}
            )
    return self.coding_days
```

How can I show commit size for each commit?

Answer (score 0):

Use `--shortstat` to get the stat for the commit

```sh
git log --date=short --after="e5e16518" --pretty="%h %an %ad" --shortstat
```

to get

```
cb807c0d clmno 2021-06-15

 4 files changed, 71 insertions(+), 15 deletions(-)
2f8de5fb clmno 2021-06-15

 4 files changed, 76 insertions(+), 23 deletions(-)
92a0e1e3 clmno 2021-06-15

 2 files changed, 9 insertions(+)
```

Now you can simply parse these to generate the JSON you need.

Comment: Thank you @clmno for your answer. Is it possible to get the result in something like this `43f4cc160, Dan ab, 2021-06-17, 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-)` so it will be easier to split those items in numpy.

Comment: @Serenity It looks like you've asked for the gates of doom to be opened - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137477/how-to-get-git-log-with-short-stat-in-one-line)

Comment: I felt a bit complex for above format to get commit hash, author, date, lines_added. removed using numpy so I wanted to know if the format I mentioned will be possible just from script or not. Haha, I agree with you now on your say on "you've asked for the gates of doom to be opened "