# How to check if a file is ahead of some previous commit in git

Tags: bash, git

I am translating a documentation of some project and I want to check which files are translated by checking the last commit from the original project.
So that I can see which percentage of translation is completed. Like there is 1000 files and only 120 of them is edited, so translation is completed by %12.

I tried things like checking the file commits, but I can't sort them.

I am going to write some bash script to automate process and I prefer it to be time efficient. How may I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [list the files changed between two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586652/6309) (or even two commits):

```
 git diff --name-only branch1 branch2 | wc -l
```

That way, you get the number of files edited in `branch2` since `branch1` (or since commit1, which is the commit where *none* of your files were edited for translation)

Comment: So, to do this I created a new branch and used git checkout to revert that branch to original version. But when I compare the two there is no output.

Comment: @Furkan Yes, but you don't even have to create branches: if *all* your commits were puerely done for translation, you can compare between HEAD and the last commit where no translation took place.

Comment: @Furkan That being said, creating a branch can be a best practice to isolate that development effort.

Comment: Okay. I used git reset instead of checkout. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @VolC yes this works too. I am not the owner of the project so your solution might be better for my situation.